# How to parse text from div to JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

The main idea is to take text from div and put it into json object. https://jsfiddle.net/4rqo1szm/1/
I can do what I want if I declare json object in javascript section but I cannot just take text() from div and make same manipulations. I commented out what I'm trying to achieve.

HTML:

```
 <div class="test"></div>
<div class="basicDiv" style="visibility: hidden;">{
    "msg"   : "apple",
    "otherInfo" : "v1"
},
{ 
    "msg"   : "orange",
    "otherInfo" : "v2"
},
{
    "msg"   : "pineapple",
    "otherInfo" : "v3"
}</div>
```

Javascript

```
//var json = JSON.stringify($(".basicDiv").text());

var json = [
{
    "msg"   : "apple",
    "otherInfo" : "v1"
},
{
    "msg"   : "orange",
    "otherInfo" : "v2"
},
{
    "msg"   : "pineapple",
    "otherInfo" : "v3"
}
] // I'd like to remove that part

var result = json.map(function(val) {
  return val.msg;
}).join(', ');


$(".test").html(result);
```

Any suggestions are welcomed. And thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the "[" and "]" is missing from the div text.

```
try{
   var json = JSON.parse("["+$(".basicDiv").text()+"]");
}catch(err){
   console.log('Invalid JSON format')
}
```

and, for parsing json text, use `JSON.parse(jsonText)` and not `JSON.stringify(jsonText)`.